# RestAssured.baseURI get the default value and not the value I provide Why

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, ssh

When I run my test on jenkins it gives following Error, I am using http port 80 and ssh port 22. Test works locally, any help would be appreciated.

```
 - Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try logging into the Jenkins system to then ping / connect to the remote systems used there. Maybe some sort of firewall issue?

Comment: ok I have debugged and found it tries to connect to 127.0.0.1 although I have hard coded the uri and ports in jenkins job as -Dsut=172.20.5.234 -Dport=80 -DsshPort=22 but still it connects to 127.0.0.1:6080

Comment: You should then enhance your question accordingly, and give as much of your setup/configuration information as possible.

Comment: ok I have debugged more and found it is getting 127.0.0.1 from RestAssured class in java
/**
     * The base URI that's used by REST assured when making requests if a non-fully qualified URI is used in the request.
     * Default value is {@value #DEFAULT_URI}.
     */
    public static String baseURI = DEFAULT_URI;

My code is as below 
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://" + config.getBaseUrl();

and 
 public String getBaseUrl() {
        System.out.println(this.getValue("sut"));
     return this.getValue("sut");
    }
where *sut* is defined in property file as
sut=172.20.5.234

Comment: Again, dont put additional information into comments. Edit/update your question instead. You dont want to force people to read through a gazillion of hard to read comments.

Comment: what should I remove ?

Comment: You are adding "more information" via comments. Dont do that. **Edit** your question, and add new content there. And then delete those comments that you added previously, like the one 2 hours old.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is HTTP port. It's very likely that an HTTP server is running already on your Jebkins machine.

You need to choose another port for your tets. Make it greater than 1023 not to conflict with well-known and system ports.

Comment: Tried other ports too

Comment: Did you change the port for both your server AND your client? Do they match?

Comment: I have changed the ports, still it says connection refused, surprisingly same ports work for another test

Comment: ok I have debugged and found it tried to connect to 127.0.0.1 although I have hard coded the uri in jenkins job as -Dsut=172.20.5.234 -Dport=80 -DsshPort=22 but still it connection to   http://127.0.0.1:6080

Comment: Your `this.getValue(String)` method, what does it do?

Comment: ok, I sorted this problem by sending values as parameter and was not using them from jenkins, that was the quickest fix